# Groovy execute a git shell command

Tags: shell, groovy

I'm trying to execute git shell command in groovy. The first is executed well but the second returns the exit code 128:

```
   def workingDir = new File("path/to/dir")
   "git add .".execute(null, workingDir)
   def p = "git reset --hard".execute( null, workingDir )
   p.text.eachLine {println it}
   println p.exitValue()
```

what's the problem with this code?

Comment: If you execute those commands in a regular shell in workingDir, do they work as expected?  Sounds like the reset is failing for some reason...

Comment: yes, both the commands work as expected in the shell in that dir

Comment: What does adding `p.consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )` print (if you add that line after the `def p` line)?

Comment: Also, wouldn't these calls be asynchronous?  So shouldn't `"git add .".execute(null, workingDir)` be: `"git add .".execute(null, workingDir).waitFor()`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/katta/5465317

Answer (score 4):

The second process is starting before the first one completes.  When the second git process starts git recognizes that there is already a git process operating in that same directory which could cause problems so it errors out.  If you read the error stream from the first process you will see something like this:

```
fatal: Unable to create 'path/to/dir/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

If you wait for the first one to finish before starting the second one, that should work.  Something like this:

```
def workingDir = new File("path/to/dir/")

def p = "git add .".execute(null, workingDir)
p.waitFor()
p = "git reset --hard".execute( null, workingDir )
p.text.eachLine {println it}
println p.exitValue()
```

Comment: I know this isn't related to the question, but I'm really liking this new stack-overflow-answering Jeff Brown. :) Really nice to see the Grails devs show up to help out on SO.