# Is it possible to Execute Git Commands from a Grails Application?

Tags: java, spring, git, grails, grails-2.0

I want to use Grails to control Git repositories to

- Create a new Repo
- add files
- merges files
- commit files

Is it possible to Execute Git Commands from a Grails Application?

Comment: Git doesn't have a public REST API.  github does.

Comment: @dmahapatro The plugin you mentioned there doesn't really have anything to do with the question.  That plugin helps manage your Grails app in a git a repo, it doesn't help you interact with git from within the Grails app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use a library like [eclipse's **JGit**](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) from within a Grails app.

Answer (score 0):

Grails is nothing but a Groovy applicaion and Groovy can execute shell commands which means you can fire git commands from your Grails app like:

```
def workingDir = new File("path/to/dir/")

def p = "git add .".execute(null, workingDir)
p.waitFor()
p = "git reset --hard".execute( null, workingDir )
p.text.eachLine {println it}
println p.exitValue()
```

Take a look at [Groovy execute a git shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537281/groovy-execute-a-git-shell-command)

In RoR you can use https://github.com/mojombo/grit‎ I'm not sure such a plugin exists for Groovy.

Comment: The jgit suggestion got -1 so I suppose someone doesn't like that, but hand coding this stuff as described here is going to get really really tedious if you want to properly deal with error codes and parsing text from the process output and all of those kinds of things.  If it is going to be reliable, you are going to end up writing a whole lot of code, basically implementing your own library that already exists.  Just my cents.